# magento1.9 version password reset link not working

Tags: magento-1.9

log: `[Thu Oct 29 19:23:51 2015] [warn] [client 116.202.135.130] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setEmailValue() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/modamstore.com/farklizevkler.com/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 688`

error line : 688:

```
$this->getLayout()
     ->getBlock('forgotPassword')
     ->setEmailValue(
```

forgot password link server error 500

http://farklizevkler.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/

help please

Comment: Have you applied Magento [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788) security patch? Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This code is pulling the layout for your page, loading the "forgotPassword" block, and then setting your email address.   It looks like that block is missing or has been renamed from your page.   Please review the XML layout for this page and block and ensure that you have the default block named "forgotPassword".

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your themes > layout > customer.xml 
make sure below handler is present in file

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change forgotten block not defined in layout file in your theme. That is why you are not able to see anything in frontend in change forgotten url

```
<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
        <label>Reset a Password</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_changeforgotten>
```